# AWS lambda s3 .net core get object type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, .net-core, aws-lambda

I'm using aws lambda with .net core than handles file uploading/folder creation in S3. On event I need to understand the type of object arrived -> if it is a folder or a file.

It is possible to filter the key by "/" that is used only for folders but I'm not sure that is a nice way of doing it.

```
    public async Task FunctionHandler(S3Event evnt, ILambdaContext context)
    {

        if (evnt.Records[0].S3.Object.Key.EndsWith("/"))
        {
            //logic for folders
        }
    }
```

What is the best practice to get this information?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried yet? Can you show us your code?

Comment: Hi Thomas,  I edited my question

Comment: How is your lambda triggered. If the lambda is triggered by a PUT to S3 bucket, then the key is always the complete file path in S3 bucket.

Comment: Yes, it is triggered by a PUT to S3 bucket, but i'm not sure that string matching is a good way for retrieving the file info.